# unzip list of tuples into numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Consider a list of tuples such as:

```
a = [(1,2), (3,4)]
```

I often find myself trying to unzip list like these into separate lists for each column value e.g.:

```
b,c = list(zip(*a))
```

In this case, `b` will be a list containing values `1` and `3`.

I often find my self wanting `b` and `c` to be numpy arrays an not lists.
In this case what I usually do is:

```
b,c = list(zip(*a))
b = np.array(b)
c = np.array(c)
```

The last two lines look cumbersome.
Is there any way to unzip a list directly into two numpy arrays without casting them directly through `numpy.array`?

Thank you

Comment: Does `b, c = np.array(a).T` do what you want? (`T` for transpose.)

Comment: oh it does indeed! thank you. please post answer so i can mark it as solved

Comment: Okay, I will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list of tuples can be converted into a 2-d numpy array by calling `np.array`.  This can then be transposed and then unpacked along the first dimension using tuple assignment:

```
b, c = np.array(a).T
```

Here this gives:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [(1,2), (3,4)]
>>> b, c = np.array(a).T   # or:  np.array(a).transpose()
>>> b
array([1, 3])
>>> c
array([2, 4])
```

Caveat: you will have a temporary array with the same number of elements as `a`, so it might be less memory-efficient than your original solution, particularly if you are unpacking into a larger number of 1d arrays.

Comment: I logged just to say this: brillant solution! well done

Comment: beautiful solution. Memory is cheap. Beauty is not.